Testing updates on a package without installing it
I'm developing an R package and locally I've installed a dev version of this. If I'm making updates to the dev version, is there a way I can install the package under a different name to compare it to the current dev version? I don't want to overwrite the dev version currently present, but I'd also like to avoid renaming the package to something like dev2.

Do yourself a favor and start using git.

@Roland I do use git, but I'm still not sure how to have two different development versions active in R so I can directly compare outputs

Install two different versions in two separate R sessions, compare. Also, what exactly do we want to compare, speed? memory efficiency, something else?

If you want to test performance between several versions (for example the main branch and another branch where you made changes), you can use the package cross. It also supports comparing branches to the CRAN version. (you could also use that for testing other things than performance, it's just my use case)

Two things to consider here: (1) Python has import pkgname as pkgabbr, R does not. There is box, but that is slightly different. (2) If you are working on a dev version and just do (e.g.) devtools::load_all(..), then when you restart R it will go back to whatever version (if any) is located in your .libPaths(). (3) Git worktrees can be useful, see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree. Using that, it's possible to have the original directory as the "released" package and a worktree as the "dev" package, then you can load_all each for the desired effect.

Okay, so really "three" not two, but it spiraled :-)

Assuming that if your package is named pkg and you do not reference pkg:: in anything within the package (that would be weird and unnecessary, though I do see it on occasion), you can use git worktrees to do what you want.1
A worktree can be in the same directory (which is my habit, prepending _ to each worktree directory name) or it can be completely separate. For instance, in a shell (bash or otherwise), if you have branches main and some dev branch I'll name fix/16-something, then you could do
### assuming you're currently in the 'main' branch
$ git worktree add ../pkg_dev fix/16-something

you will have two side-by-side directories, ./pkg (the original, currently editing main) and ./pkg_dev (the new directory, currently editing fix/16-something). If you look in ./pkg_dev/.git, normally it's a directory but in a worktree it's a file that indicates where the real .git directory is located. All git commands in ./pkg_dev work as one would expect.
With this, you can now temporarily edit ./pkg_dev/DESCRIPTION so that it has Package: pkg_dev instead. And now you can do
### either one of these, for the unchanged prod version
library(pkg)
devtools::load_all("path/to/pkg")

### and this for the local dev version
devtools::load_all("path/to/pkg_dev") # package named `pkg_dev::`

Granted, I discussed having "main" be the original directory and pkg being the original package, you can also switch: have your original package directory (with the real ./.git/ subdir) be the in-dev branch, then git worktree add ../some_path main and temporarily rename that package.
Notes:

Actually, you can still use worktrees to do it even if you do have pkg:: references within your package code, though to do it right you would likely need to make temporary changes of every use from pkg:: to pkg_dev:: within the code. Still quite possible but a bit more onerous. Over to you!


by path, do you mean .libPaths() or any path that you have your development files in?  In another word, do you work directly on the path that your R loads library from, instead of creating a copy of package at separate path for you to play around with?
